# I want to find out how much is my database using and how much CPU are the function on that database is using

Tags: sql-server

As I stated in the title, I want to find out how much cpu time my database is using VS how much cpu time all of the functions on that database are using.  I want to show that the functions that are running on this database are the most consuming in terms of CPU.

So far I have found nothing of any sort so any tips helping me find a solution would help.

Answer (score 1):

This query might be useful for you:

```
-- Look at UDF execution statistics (Query 53) (UDF Stats by DB)
SELECT TOP (25) DB_NAME(database_id) AS [Database Name], 
           OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) AS [Function Name],
           total_worker_time, execution_count, total_elapsed_time,  
           total_elapsed_time/execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],  
           last_elapsed_time, last_execution_time, cached_time, [type_desc] 
FROM sys.dm_exec_function_stats WITH (NOLOCK) 
ORDER BY total_worker_time DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

It will return you the CPU used by the cached UDF functions in your database.
Combine that with something like this:

```
-- Get CPU utilization by database (Query 36) (CPU Usage by Database)
WITH DB_CPU_Stats
AS
(SELECT pa.DatabaseID, DB_Name(pa.DatabaseID) AS [Database Name], SUM(qs.total_worker_time/1000) AS [CPU_Time_Ms]
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs WITH (NOLOCK)
 CROSS APPLY (SELECT CONVERT(int, value) AS [DatabaseID] 
              FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(qs.plan_handle)
              WHERE attribute = N'dbid') AS pa
 GROUP BY DatabaseID)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [CPU_Time_Ms] DESC) AS [CPU Rank],
       [Database Name], [CPU_Time_Ms] AS [CPU Time (ms)], 
       CAST([CPU_Time_Ms] * 1.0 / SUM([CPU_Time_Ms]) OVER() * 100.0 AS DECIMAL(5, 2)) AS [CPU Percent]
FROM DB_CPU_Stats
WHERE DatabaseID <> 32767 -- ResourceDB
ORDER BY [CPU Rank] OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Which gives you CPU used per database.

Keep in mind, these are based on cached values, so take with a grain of salt and keep in mind your own system and don't blindly follow it after one execution. But they should give you some indications of what you're looking for.

These queries are not mine, and are taken from the library of Glenn Berry, feel free to check them out:
https://glennsqlperformance.com/resources/

Comment: What happens if you run your session out of TempDB but it only queries items in another database, such as `use tempdb; select * from mydatabase.dbo.hugetable`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [First Responder Kit](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/), in particular [`sp_BlitzCache`](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/), to find your worst performing queries:

> You have a SQL Server and you’re not sure which queries are causing your biggest performance problems. You don’t know where to start or if there are hidden queries that are making your main queries slower. You want a fast tool to find the worst queries in the SQL Server plan cache, tell you why they’re bad, and even tell you what you can do about them. sp_BlitzCache® provides the in-depth analysis that you’re looking for.

Run it with the parameter `@SortOrder = 'CPU'` to sort the worst performing queries by CPU first.